# Create extra partition for /var on an OpenVZ

Tags: partitioning, logging, container, openvz

I have an OpenVZ Debian Wheezy and I've learned that it's generally advised to create an own partition for `/var`, in order to prevent logs from filling the system partition.

My question is if it is common to do so on an OpenVZ container and if so how do I accomplish it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not common for OpenVZ, although this is often a personal preference. There is no technical need, since container disk can be extended dynamically, while a container is running, without affecting any container operations.

Disk in OpenVZ acts like quota to use the underlying host disk, this is why it's safe to extend the quota/increase limit.